# JPA one-to-many vs many-to-many - Books and authors

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, netbeans

For a JPA project I got asked to implement the following situation:

A book can have many authors.

Also there is an UML that states that an author can have many books and a book can have many authors.

I am a beginner when it comes to this subject.
Do I need an many to many relation (with an intersection table)
or do I need a bidirectional one to many relation.

Also the bidirectional part of a one to many relation confuses me. If anybody could explain this with an example that would be nice.

Comment: An author has many books, and a book has many author, so it's clearly a ManyToMany association: Book needs a collection of authors, and Author needs a collection of books. What confuses you? The JPA documentation, and the Hibernate documentation, contain plenty of examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bidirectional associations allow you to navigate both sides of this relationship both in Object space as well as in JPA/Hibernate Query Language.

In your example, a database many-to-many association is mandatory (meaning you have a BOOK, an AUTHOR and a BOOK_AUTHOR link table). Hibernate offers two possibilities for mapping this relationship:

1. You can model this with two entities: Book and Author, each one having a @ManyToMany association to the other (one being the owning side while the other being the inverse one)
2. You can have three entities: Book, Author and BookAuthor and this time Book have a @OneToMany association to BookAuthor and Author has also a @OneToMany association to BookAuthor. This option allows you two map additional link table columns (BOOK_AUTHOR creation_time).